# What is a modern OOP php image processing library with engines?

Tags: php, image, oop, unit-testing, image-processing

We're evaluating if we have to re-invent the wheel because of the lack of good libraries or we simply can't find one. We have pretty clear and strict requirements:

- Must be MIT
- Must have Unit Tests (phpunit)
- Must support engines (gd, imagick, imagick shell...)
- Must be php 5+

The best thing we've found so far is Asido but its pretty much outdated and abandoned.

Any libraries you know that match our needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine)? It meets all your requirements.

I had used it once (however for a very simple image manipulation) and it turend out to be a pretty useful and easy-to-use library.

Comment: Thank you (again ;)! I've spent some time looking at it and its pretty much what we want at least for our own projects which are already using 5.3!